# What is _uses_learning_phase in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to write my own recurrent layer in Keras and noticed this line in the [Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L920) source:

```
    # Properly set learning phase on output tensor.
    if 0 < self.dropout + self.recurrent_dropout:
        if training is None:
            output._uses_learning_phase = True
```

Checking the [backend](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3086) code for `in_train_phase`:

```
if training is None:
    training = learning_phase()
    uses_learning_phase = True
else:
    uses_learning_phase = False
```

This is rather confusing. Isn't "training" the "learning phase"?! I guess more importantly, do I need to set `_uses_learning_phase` on `output` in my custom recurrent layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Intro*
A "Training Flag" is meant [to enable a Model](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3086-L3087) (or Layer) to behave different from training when it predicts results or is being tested.
Depending on the backend used, Keras may need to implement its own boolean "training flag" (on [CNTK](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/backend/cntk_backend.py#L90-L92) as for Keras 2.2.4) or can use a native backend tensor (like with [Tensorflow](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3122-L3125)) Therefor dynamic-purpose code was integrated.

As consequence Layer class [has a property](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L56-L58) described as followed:

```
uses_learning_phase: Whether any operation
    of the layer uses `K.in_training_phase()`
    or `K.in_test_phase()`.
```

and output tensors may be given an attribute _uses_learning_phase which is read by the property. If any output tensor has the attribute (and it is true), the layer's property returns true.

*Usage in Keras's Recurrent layer*
Your code snippet comes from keras/layers/recurrent.py and when calling the private _generate_dropout_mask method, the backend's operation creator "in_train_phase()" is [being called](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2306-L2311). Therefore the output tensor's flag "_uses_learning_phase" is being set.

*Explanation of quoted backend code*

in_training_phase() and in_test_phase() are [just](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/backend/cntk_backend.py#L111-L112) [the](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/backend/theano_backend.py#L1677-L1684) [same](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3129-L3146). "training" is an optional argument and references the Training Flag. If the argument is not given, the Training Flag is refered automatically at

```
training = learning_phase()
```

However, the output tensor's attribute _uses_learning_phase is only set (and set True), if Training Flag is a tensor of the backend AND optional training argument was not set. (This may also explain, why a layer needs to set _uses_learning_phase itself, but I see no usecase for creating an operation via in_test_phase without flagging the output tensor. For now, assume there is one.)